# Python v3 to store a len value and hold in a variable

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish is to use the `len` function on a list , which I have done and I have got the correct length value, but furthermore to somehow either hold the beginning value of the length (since the number of objects in the list change) or store the beginning value of the length in a variable, then to hold it (so it doesn't change).

This context is using `.extend` to add questions to a list called `Quests` (10 questions) and as each question is answered, it is deleted from the list, hence why the `len(Quests)` changes.

```
Quests = []

Quests.extend (["Q1","Q2","Q3"...])

len(Quests)  # To store this value once and before the code runs again.

del Quests
```

Comment: you should add some of your code

Comment: And what have you done so far?:)

Comment: It's terrifically unclear what you're asking, but it sounds like the solution is simply: `l = len(my_list)`...!?!

Comment: Why don't you just assign the length as you do the list? And why do you `del` the list afterwards?

Comment: sorry, im not very good at explaing it and my code is 100 Ln's long, not very clear to read. Thats what I am looking for deceze, I just need to save that variable somehow so it doesnt change.

Comment: jonrsharpe, del (each question one at a time) is a requirement for the program i am writing and i will try that.

Comment: Well, that variable *won't* change unless you change it!

Comment: @CHOCOBLOCK `del l` dereferences the whole list; `l.pop()` would remove a single question from it. Please provide a [mcve] that actually recreates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
len(Quests)  # To store this value once and before the code runs again.
```

you only call a function `len()`, you do not store the value. To store it you have to assign it to a variable:

```
l = len(Quest)
```

and the use `l` when you need this value.

Comment: thanks for the explanation "and the use 'l' when you need this value."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a spot in my code where I assigned the variable to the len(Quests) so that it doesn't decrease by the del.